# Shopify, Adding another column for Shipping details in product page

Tags: html, css, shopify

I want to add another shipping column in between two existing column in my product page in Shopify and also link it to my pages called "shipping" but I can't seem to find out how. Here is the existing code

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
  <a href="#tab-description" class="selected">{{'products.product.description' | t}}</a>
  <a href="#tab-review" class="">{{'products.product.customer_reviews' | t}}</a>
  {%- if product.featured_image.alt contains 'iframe' -%}
  <a href="#tab-video">{{'products.product.video' | t}}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">{{product.description}}</div>
<div id="tab-review" class="tab-content"><div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{product.metafields.spr.reviews}}</div></div>
{%- if product.featured_image.alt contains 'iframe' -%}
<div id="tab-video" class="tab-content">{{product.featured_image.alt}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
```

[The existing descriptions and reviews in my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGsA.png)

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
  <a href="#tab-description" class="selected">{{'products.product.description' | t}}</a>
  <a href="#tab-new">Tab Heading</a>
  <a href="#tab-review" class="">{{'products.product.customer_reviews' | t}}</a>
  {%- if product.featured_image.alt contains 'iframe' -%}
  <a href="#tab-video">{{'products.product.video' | t}}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">{{product.description}}</div>
<div id="tab-new" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">{{pages.shipping.content}} <a href="/shiiping/page/link">Shipping</a></div>
<div id="tab-review" class="tab-content"><div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{product.metafields.spr.reviews}}</div></div>
{%- if product.featured_image.alt contains 'iframe' -%}
<div id="tab-video" class="tab-content">{{product.featured_image.alt}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for the code, however i want the"Tab Content Shipping" to be what i wrote it in my page " shipping" if you could modified the code, i would be thankful. cheers :)