# Shopify, Changing the text into what i wrote in a page

Tags: html, css, shopify

I want the"Tab Content Shipping" to be what i wrote in my page " Shipping" under the Shipping column in my product page. Here's the code

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
<a href="#tab-description" class="selected">{{'products.product.description' | t}}</a>
 <a href="#tab-new">Tab Heading</a>
 <a href="#tab-review" class="">{{'products.product.customer_reviews' | t}}
</a>
  {%- if product.featured_image.alt contains 'iframe' -%}
 <a href="#tab-video">{{'products.product.video' | t}}</a>
 {%- endif -%}
</div>
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">
{{product.description}}</div>
<div id="tab-new" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">Tab Content <a 
href="/shiiping/page/link">Shipping</a></div>
<div id="tab-review" class="tab-content"><div id="shopify-product-reviews" 
data-id="{{product.id}}">{{product.metafields.spr.reviews}}</div></div>
{%- if product.featured_image.alt contains 'iframe' -%}
<div id="tab-video" class="tab-content">{{product.featured_image.alt}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
```

[Here is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMB21.png)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div id="tab-new" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">Tab Content <a 
href="/shiiping/page/link">Shipping</a></div>
```

to

```
<div id="tab-new" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">{{pages.shipping.content}}<a 
href="/shiiping/page/link">Shipping</a></div>
```

Note further that you should probably correct "shiiping" to "shipping" both in this code and in your [the code in the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387162/shopify-adding-another-column-for-shipping-details-in-product-page).